# does go excecute all conditions in if statement?

Tags: if-statement, go

Example:

`if function1(input) && function2(input) {}`

In this case would `function2(input)` be executed if `function1(input)` returns false?

Comment: Tip: Consult the spec, it is readable. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Logical_operators

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are asking about is called [Short Circuiting,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and yes, Go does it.

In the [language spec,](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Logical_operators) it says that

> Logical operators apply to boolean values and yield a result of the same type as the operands. The right operand is evaluated conditionally.

This means that, in your case, if `function1` returned false, `function2` would not be called.

See an example for [`&&` here](https://play.golang.org/p/RAMY4386Ct) and for [`||` here.](https://play.golang.org/p/vCU3K-J2t6)

Answer (score 4):

No. Go uses standard conditional shortcut logic - the first `false` result in a string of `&&` conditions will stop evaluation of further conditions (because it cannot yield a `true` result no matter what the other conditions are). Likewise, the first `true` result in a string of `||` conditions will stop evaluation because it cannot yield a `false` result no matter what the other conditions are.